# dask geopandas apply(): AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, geopandas, dask

I have a function that takes a GeoSeries as input and returns a value. When I call said function over all rows in a large geodataframe (gdf) with gdf.apply(), setting the output as a new column in the dataframe, it works:

```
# successful:
gdf = gpd.read_file(inShp)
gdf['output_column'] = gdf.apply(lambda f: myFunction(f, arg), axis = 1)
```

But when I try to split the dataframe up with dask_geopandas and call the same function:

```
# not successful:
ddf = dask_geopandas.from_geopandas(gdf, npartitions=2)
out = ddf.apply(lambda f: myFunction(f, arg), axis = 1, meta=metaArg)
comp = out.compute()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

The same error occurs when metaArg = ddf; ddf._meta; or gdf.

If my function is something simple such as the following, I still get the same error on out.compute():

```
def myFunction(gs):

    return len(gs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try to make a reproducible example?

Comment: The value passed to `metaArg` might be wrong? (I suppose it expects a Series and not a DataFrame, that could explain the error)

Answer (score 0):

As if happens, adding this line before setting `ddf` makes it work. Seems like a bug?

```
gdf['name'] = 'name'
```